# Paste in visual block mode

Tags: cut-copy-paste, visual-block

I would like to copy some text at the beginning of several lines.

What I have is:

```
line

111
222
333
444
```

And what I want is:

```
line

line 111
line 222
line 333
line 444
```

I know that I can add `line`  at the beginning of each lines by entering `VISUAL BLOCK` mode and select the beginning of the lines, then pressing `Shift+i`, writting `line`  and then press `Esc`, but I would like a way to copy in visual block mode instead of writting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you have yanked `line` from visual mode, you…

1. move the cursor to the first `1` of `111`,
2. press `<C-v>` to enter visual-block mode,
3. extend the visual selection to the first `4` of `444`,
4. press `I` to enter insert mode,
5. insert the content of the default register, the `line` you just yanked, with `<C-r>"`,
6. insert a space,
7. leave insert mode with `<Esc>`.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

and another one:

1. `yiw` copy "line"
2. `jj` move to "111"
3. `<C-v>}` select first col
4. `I<space><space><esc>` insert 2 spaces
5. `gv` reselect
6. `p` paste "line"

[image: asciicast]

Answer (score 0):

In your example you not only want to copy but also to duplicate `line` four times.

I don't have a solution for that but if you have:

```
line1
line2
line3
line4

111
222
333
444
```

You can simply block select (<kbd>Ctrl v</kbd>) and yank the block

```
line1
line2
line3
line4
```

And past (`P`) it in front of:

```
111
222
333
444
```

It will give you:

```
line1 111
line2 222
line3 333
line4 444
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I knew about this solution, but indeed I only have one block line selection that I want to paste over multiple lines block selection.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback :-) I have no other idea unfortunately :-|

Comment: You can create the initial block with `yy3p`